# Is it possible to upload Vignette files directly, without using the web interface?

Tags: javascript, css, image, vignette

In the project I'm working on, we have web resource files (e.g. JS, CSS, images, etc) stored in Vignette.

As a web developer I find this cumbersome to work with, since I frequently update these files, and since each upload of a file requires several clicks and waiting for up to 5 seconds on each click.

It would be awesome if I could instead update the files via FTP or some kind of HTTP interface, etc.

Is it possible to set this up?

Comment: OK, looks like no one knows. I'm going to examine the HTTP pipeline with Fiddler and see if I can figure out how to fake the POSTs that upload the file.

Comment: by "vignette" do you mean VCM, Portal?

Answer (score 2):

If the files were uploaded in Vignette Application Portal as secondary files for a style tag, they end up buried in the template staging area for your VAP web server.

Something like: weblogic/userprojects/domains/previewdom/servers/previewserver1/stage/vignette_portal/portal/templates/*HASH*/Uploaded files

The *HASH* above denotes a hash Vignette correlates to a VAP site instance (if you only have one site, it will be the only hash folder in the templates directory).

Note: This is only a temporary place to make changes CSS and image files, after the server restarts, directory names may change and files may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit/upload primary files (JSP, GIF, CSS, HTML, ...) for the following component types over WebDAV:

• Secondary Pages
 • Styles
 • Grids

More details can be found in the Developer's Guide (Editing Site Components Using WebDAV).